# Simple json.load(file) in python command line returns an error and empties the file

Tags: python, json

I ran these simple commands in python and json.load(file) returns an error, but everything seems to be OK. On top of that, the command seems to erase all the data in the file. What am I not getting?

```
>>> dictionary
{'Nome': 'Gabriel', 'Idade': '24', 'Sobrenome': 'Aguiar'}
>>> file = open('test.json','w')
>>> json.dump(dictionary,file)
>>> file.close()
>>> file = open('test.json','r')
>>> file.read()
'{"Nome": "Gabriel", "Idade": "24", "Sobrenome": "Aguiar"}'
>>> json.load(file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>> file.read()
''
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is not emptied, it is just "used up" by your previous instruction:

```
file.read()
```

If you closed and reopened the file:

```
file.close()
file = open('test.json','r')
file.read()
file.close()
file = open('test.json','r')
json.load(file)
file.close()
```

you'd get correct result. BTW a more elegant way of opening a file (which does not require explicit closing) is:

```
with open('test.json','r') as file:
    json.load(file)
```

This executes `file.close()` automatically upon exit from the block.

Comment: It worked with the "with ... as ... :"
Thank you so much!